# Jetpack compose - nested navigation with 1.0.0-alpha02

Tags: android, android-architecture-navigation, android-jetpack-compose

After navigation-compose 1.0.0-alpha01 is released, I tried to play with nested navigation in conjunction with bottom navigation bar.
It allows to switch between tabs and enter to nested screens with saving tabs state even after screen rotation

https://github.com/ochkarik05/try-compose

After updating  compose to 1.0.0-alpha07 and navigation-compose to 1.0.0-alpha02, everything stopped working after screen rotation, for example, back button has no effect. Broken branch are here:

https://github.com/ochkarik05/try-compose/tree/feature/update_libs

Now I can not find how to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same issue as well, and confirmed that downgrading from nav `alpha02` to `alpha01` fixes the issue.

I logged https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/173563115 since it seems to be a bug within the library itself. You should be able to turn on notifications for that ticket to receive any updates.

Comment: I believe that it was fixed in https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1507838/, but haven't check if it is already working